# How to split column on the first occurrence of a string?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in the below format. I would like to split the word before the '.' in username column and keep the rest as a different column

```
+----+--------+
|Name|Username|
+----+--------+
| ABC|a.b.cdef|
+----+--------+
```

I want to split user name as

```
+----+--------+---+------+
|Name|Username|  A|     B|
+----+--------+---+------+
| ABC|a.b.cdef|  a|b.cdef|
+----+--------+---+------+
```

The length of the prefix (before the first `.`) is not fixed, hence I couldn't use the `substring` standard function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to split on the first `.`, which you can achieve with regex look around. This will save you from the `regexp_replace` step:

```scala
(df.withColumn("Username", split($"Username", "(?<=^[^.]*)\\."))
   .withColumn("A", $"Username"(0))
   .withColumn("B", $"Username"(1))).show

+----+-----------+---+------+
|Name|   Username|  A|     B|
+----+-----------+---+------+
| ABC|[a, b.cdef]|  a|b.cdef|
+----+-----------+---+------+
```

Detail on pattern `(?<=^[^.]*)\\.`:

- Use look behind `?<=` to restrict the `.` to split on;
- `^[^.]*` matches a pattern from the beginning of the string which doesn't contain a `.`. Notice the first `^` means beginning of string. `[^.]` is a character class that matches any character except `.` and `*` is a quantifier which means zero or more.

Combined together the pattern matches the first `.` in the string.

Answer (score 3):

For this particular case, I'd (re)consider a user-defined function (and avoid a regexp since it might be hard to understand after a couple of weeks).

```
val splitFirst = udf { (s: String) => s.split("\\.", 2) }

scala> data.withColumn("AB", splitFirst($"username")).show
+----+--------+-----------+
|Name|Username|         AB|
+----+--------+-----------+
| ABC|a.b.cdef|[a, b.cdef]|
+----+--------+-----------+

val solution = data
  .withColumn("AB", splitFirst($"username"))
  .withColumn("A", $"AB"(0))
  .withColumn("B", $"AB"(1))
scala> solution.show
+----+--------+-----------+---+------+
|Name|Username|         AB|  A|     B|
+----+--------+-----------+---+------+
| ABC|a.b.cdef|[a, b.cdef]|  a|b.cdef|
+----+--------+-----------+---+------+
```

The trick is to use the proper [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)):

> **public String[] split​(String regex, int limit)** Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.
>
> If the limit is positive then the pattern will be applied at most limit - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than limit, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.