# How to split a text file into 2 columns based on multiple space chars as seperator with scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split, apache-spark-sql

I'm having difficulty on splitting a text data file with delimiter "    " (multiple spaces) into data frame columns. My loaded data file looks like this:

```
results1.show()

+--------------------+
|                 all|
+--------------------+
|1     hjvh hjk 9 gkk|
|2     yjg vv 87 9bh |
|3     kjn 90j jn kjn|
|4     hb jkbkj j jb |
|....                |
|....                |
|....                |
|9997  jn kjn kjn jkn|
|9998  njkj jn8 98 in|
|9999  nkj kjnkn kjnk|
```

I want it to seperate into 2 seperate columns like this:

```
|     No|          Address |
+-------+------------------|
|      1|    hjvh hjk 9 gkk|  
|      2|    yjg vv 87 9bh |      
|      3|    kjn 90j jn kjn|     
|      4|    hb jkbkj j jb |  
|     ..|             
|     ..|             
|     ..|             
|   9997|    jn kjn kjn jkn| 
|   9998|    njkj jn8 98 in|
|   9999|    nkj kjnkn kjnk|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split the column at the first occurrence of `space` using regex look around.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586851/how-to-split-column-on-the-first-occurrence-of-a-string#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20comment-,2,Combined%20together%20the%20pattern%20matches%20the%20first%20.%20in%20the%20string.,-Share) for a detailed explanation.
The difference is that your delimiter is `space (\s)`

```scala
results1.withColumn("Temp", split($"all", "(?<=^[^\\s]*)\\s"))
.withColumn("No", $"Temp"(0))
.withColumn("Address", $"Temp"(1))
.drop("all","Temp")
.show()
```

Output

```
+----+--------------------+
|  No|             Address|
+----+--------------------+
|   1|      hjvh hjk 9 gkk|
|   2|      yjg vv 87 9bh |
|   3|      kjn 90j jn kjn|
|   4|    hb jkbkj j jb...|
|9997|      jn kjn kjn jkn|
|9998|      njkj jn8 98 in|
|9999|      nkj kjnkn kjnk|
+----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split`.

```py
df.withColumn('all', f.expr("split(all, '[ ]{2,}')")) \
  .select(f.col('all')[0], f.col('all')[1]) \
  .toDF('No', 'Address').show()

+----+--------------+
|  id|         value|
+----+--------------+
|   1|hjvh hjk 9 gkk|
|   2|yjg vv 87 9bh |
|   3|kjn 90j jn kjn|
|   4|hb jkbkj j jb |
|9997|jn kjn kjn jkn|
|9998|njkj jn8 98 in|
|9999|nkj kjnkn kjnk|
+----+--------------+
```

Comment: how is the row splitting it into two seperate cols? can you please explain this part "split(all, '[ ]{2,}')" ?

Comment: That means the spaces more than 2 times.